# Problems to perform PostgreSQL restore

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm having trouble performing the restore from a dump. The scenario is as follows: I am migrating an environment from GCP to AWS, and at the moment I am working on the migration of the bank.

A partner dumped db that is in GCP and placed the file on AWS S3 (I don't know the command he used to perform the dump).

I created an EC2 in the AWS environment and copied the dump from S3 to EC2 (the file is 13 GB). I also created the RDS to host the new db with all the correct security group settings.

Here comes the problem, I connect to the RDS from the server (EC2) without problems, but when doing the restore using `pg_restore` I get the following error message: `pg_restore: too many command line arguments (first is "dbclient. dump ").`

The complete command I used was this:

```
pg_restore -h client-aurora-cluster-hmg-legado-instance-1.c23ltjbbz7ms.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -U postgres -d db_hmg_legado dbclient.dump -W
```

OK, I changed the approach. I tried with `psql` instead of `pg_restore` and then the command was like this:

```
psql -h client-aurora-cluster-hmg-legado-instance-1.c23ltjbbz7ms.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -U postgres -d db_hmg_legado dbclient.dump -W
```

Only this time it worked !!!!

But I received some error messages while performing the restore. Which I put below:

```
psql: dbclient.dump: 23: ERROR: schema "dw" already exists
CREATE EXTENSION
psql: dbclient.dump: 37: ERROR: must be owner of extension hstore
CREATE EXTENSION
psql: dbclient.dump: 51: ERROR: must be owner of extension intarray
CREATE EXTENSION
psql: dbclient.dump: 65: ERROR: must be owner of extension pg_trgm
CREATE EXTENSION
psql: dbclient.dump: 79: ERROR: must be owner of extension unaccent
```

But the restore takes a long time and is partially finished.

In general I wanted to understand why pg_restore didn't work. Has anyone ever experienced this?

And about these owner errors does anyone know how to resolve this using psql?

Comment: No. Im using Postgres 9.6

Answer (score 1):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) the file to be restored is the last parameter and it is specified without a "switch". But you are using `-W` *after* the dump file. Move the `-W` parameter somewhere before that (although it's usually not necessary to begin with)

So you need something like this:

```
pg_restore -W -h ... -U postgres -d db_hmg_legado dbclient.dump
```

However, if the restore worked when using `psql` then the dump file is a "plain text" dump which can't be restored using `pg_restore` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the errors:

You should restore the dump into an empty database that doesn't contain any schemas except the default ones.

You need a superuser for `CREATE EXTENSION`, which you don't have in a hosted database. So pre-install these extensions with the techniques that Amazon provides, then restore the dump and ignore the errors.